# Java/Android override methods

Tags: java, android, methods, overriding

I am practicing Android for internship and I have been able to write a class that handles the geolocation for me trying to find the best location and I keep updating things whenever onLocationChanged is called.

Now I need to use my location to put Markers on a GoogleMaps I could obviously change the onLocationChanged method from my class handling geolocation but I would love to extract the action I need to do outside of the class because in the future I might need my current location to perform a lot of different things.

```
package com.example.soueuls.swipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GeoLocation {
    private final Context context;
    private final LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private int updateLimit = 0;
    private long timeLimit = 0;

    public GeoLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (this.currentLocation == null) {
            this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
            if (isBetterLocation(GeoLocation.this.currentLocation, newLocation)) {
                GeoLocation.this.currentLocation = newLocation;
            }

            if (--GeoLocation.this.updateLimit == 0) {
                GeoLocation.this.stopLocationUpdate();
            } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 > GeoLocation.this.timeLimit) {
                GeoLocation.this.stopLocationUpdate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    private boolean isBetterLocation(Location currentLocation, Location newLocation) {
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            return true;
        }

        int twoMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 2;

        long timeDelta = newLocation.getTime() - currentLocation.getTime();
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (newLocation.getAccuracy() - currentLocation.getAccuracy());

        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > twoMinutes;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -twoMinutes;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(currentLocation.getProvider(), newLocation.getProvider());

        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    public void setUpdateLimit(int limit) {
        this.updateLimit = limit;
    }

    public void setTimeLimit(long limit) {
        this.timeLimit = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + limit;
    }

    public void setLocationUpdate(String provider, int minTimeInterval, int minDistance) {
        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTimeInterval, minDistance, this.locationListener);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdate() {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
    }

    public Location getCurrentLocation() {
        return this.currentLocation;
    }
}
```

Here is GeoLocation class I would still need to update this.currentLocation each time onLocationChanged is called.

But I would like to be able to detect whenever onLocationChanged iscalled to perform update inside my activity which is outside this class.

How could I do it ?

EDIT :
Inside the onResume method of the activity I am trying to listen I do

```
GeolocationListener locationListener = new GeolocationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
                System.out.println("OHOHOH");
                displayWeatherInformation(weatherCache, geoLocation.getCurrentLocation());
            }
        };
```

Comment: You should implement the listener pattern.

Comment: listener for sure! I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use listeners

you add the interface to your Geolocation class

```
public class GeoLocation {
```

add your listeners

```
   // listeners
   private List<LocationListener> listeners = new ArrayList<LocationListener>();
   public void addListener(LocationListener l){
      listeners.add(l);
   }
   public void removeListener(LocationListener l){
      listeners.remove(l);
   }
```

then inside your `private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()` you put

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
        if (isBetterLocation(GeoLocation.this.currentLocation, newLocation)) {
            GeoLocation.this.currentLocation = newLocation;
            for(LocationListener l:listeners){
                l.onLocationChanged(newLocation);
            }
        }
   ... the rest of the code
```

then any class can register to receive updates on your Geolocation class

**edit:**

declare your activity like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        geoLocation.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override     
    public void onPause(){
        geoLocation.removeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I am having some hard time registering to my Geolocation class. I will update my initial post with what I am doing.

Comment: instead of creating a `new` you should just declare the activity like this: `public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener`, then you write the method `onLocationChanged(Location)` inside the activity and onResume/onPause you have to call `geoLocation.addListener(this);` and `geoLocation.removeListener(this);`

Comment: please see my edit. And don't ask how you get a reference to the `geolocation` that's a different question and the answer is `Singleton`

Answer (score 0):

You can use observer pattern-the activity registers itself in onResume() with the GeoLocation class to receive updates and in onPause() unregisters itself.

There are lot of material on net to learn observer pattern-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern